# Parallelise Model Selection for Neural Networks

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm coding up my own Neural Network (for learning purposes, not real use) and I am currently in the model selection phase where I cross-validate my NN with a set of parameters.  I am currently using a for loop to loop through the `numpy` array `reg_range`:

```
def model_selection(nn, trainX, trainY, reg_range, k_folds=5):
    # reg_range = the range of regularization parameters to search over
    res = []
    for i, reg in enumerate(reg_range):
        print "Testing", i+1, "/", len(reg_range), "parameters"
        nn.reset()
        res.append(cross_validation(nn, trainX, trainY, reg=reg, k_folds=k_folds))
    return res

mod_sel = model_selection(nn1, trainX, trainY, reg_params)
```

The `cross_validation` function returns an 1D numpy.array with the accuracy of each CV run.  How can I parallelise this code and still have `mod_sel` in the same order as `reg_params`?  I'm interested to see how one can do it with the `multiprocessing` library as well as with `IPython`.

Hope this is clear, I tried to leave out (in my mind at least) the non-relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my question - why am I not getting any responses?  I thought this would be very straightforward to parallelise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what a solution looks like with `multiprocessing`. Since it seems that you are mutating your nn during cross_validation you are either going to want to create a `clone()` method on your nn like I have stubbed in my answer or you are going to want to alter cross_validation to not mutate. I had to make some assumptions about how `reset()` works.

```
import multiprocessing
import functools

def model_selection(nn, trainX, trainY, reg, k_folds=5):
    nn = nn.clone() # since you seem to be mutating this 
                    # you are going to want to copy it and mutate the copy instead
    return cross_validation(nn, trainX, trainY, reg=reg, k_folds=k_folds))

nn1.reset()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
f = functools.partial(model_selection, nn1, trainX, trainY)
model_sel = pool.map(f, reg_params)
```